# Has "Validate" been removed from Eclipse Juno SDK for Windows?

Tags: android, eclipse

**Summary:**

"Validate" is no longer an option in Eclipse Juno SDK 4.2.2 for Windows under the right-click menu.

**Details:**

After all my files have been installed in an Android project in Eclipse and Cleaned, I usually use Validate to see what problems are generated from my HTML files. However, that option under the right-click menu is no longer available. I've created several Android apps and the option has always been there.

**Unsuccessful steps taken to fix:**

- Ran SDK Manager for updates (there were none).
- Did Clean all projects and Refresh.
- File > Restart.
- Exited program, then restarted.
- Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
- Made sure it was the Java perspective.
- Reset Java perspective to default.
- Checked menu drop-downs for relocation.
- Help > Search > 'validate' and 'validation'
- Help > Index > 'validate' and 'validation'

(This question has been answered in the comments below.)

Comment: No. The Validation preference pages and actions come from the Web Tools Platform, which you can find in the Java EE download.  I'm surprised that the ADT is running without it being present.  Which JRE are you using.

Comment: Prefs > Java > Installed JREs says, jdk1.7.0_09. I can click on Java EE perspective and not see the Validation option. I believe I have Eclipse Classic. Should I download the Eclipse SDK for Java EE Developers instead?

Comment: You shouldn't need to go that far.  http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F

Comment: That brought the tool back! Thanks for your help!